# When given a list of the same instance of a class, how does deepcopy behave

Tags: python, python-3.x, copy, deep-copy

When given a list of the same instance of a class, how does deepcopy behave?

Does it keep looping through the list and calling copy() or does it create a new instance and assign it to all of the old instances?

Comment: This is noted in https://docs.python.org/3/library/copy.html - it will depend on the implementation of the class.

Comment: I skipped over that part by mistake, nice to know how smartly it was implemented.

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT:** As @jonrsharpe has noted https://docs.python.org/3/library/copy.html points out that DeepCopy has a memo dictionary to stop the normal problems arising. This Memo dict stores each thing it copies so any duplicates are the same instance as the first.

After some testing here are my results.

```py
from copy import deepcopy

class Test:
    pass

test_instance = Test()

orginal_list = [a, a, a]

new_list = deepcopy(orginal_list)

print([id(x) for x in orginal_list])
print([id(x) for x in new_list])
```

This returns:

1 | [139819056140240, 139819056140240, 139819056140240]
2 | [139819056139760, 139819056139760, 139819056139760]

It seems it creates a new instance and assigns it to all of the old instances. It seems that deepcopy is far more complex than I first thought.

(I'm posting this answer as I thought the was some surprising behavior that could trip some people up (as it almost did for me). I also can't find any reference to this online. If anyone has a better explanation I would be grateful to hear it.)